# Isn't it redundant to use "!!" in an if statement since if statments already check for truthy?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, type-coercion

From my understanding `!!` is the preferred way to ensure a value is of **Boolean** type. So there are many cases where `!!` would be appropriate to use. However, in an `if` statement wouldn't it be redundant to use `!!` on a value since `if` statements already check for truthy?

```js
var user = 'username123'

if (!!user) {
  // arbitrary code
}
```

So, I know I used a string here but it really shouldn't matter what type the variable is because I was under the assumption that the whole point of using `!!` is to ensure a **Boolean** type. In other words, `!!user` is just another way of doing `Boolean(user)`. After carefully reading through the MDN docs for `If..else` it seems pretty clear that `if` statments already do this. Why then is there a need for `!!` inside an `if` statement? Or am I wrong and does `!!` actually convert values into a Boolean type more accurately or differently than the type coercion done by the `if` statment? Or is it one of those cases where I'm mostly right but there are exceptions where the conversions would result in different Boolean values?

Comment: Yes it's redundant.

Comment: this is just ninja code, 2 characters added instead of 9 ; mostly used on ternary operators, there is no devil

Comment: It's redundant so long as you don't explicitly need a boolean, so in a singular check for truthiness. But there are comparisons that will yield unexpected results if not explicitly coerced ie `([] == false) // -> true` where as `(!![] == false) //-> false`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is redundant. The `if` statement condition is always coerced to a boolean. The same applies for ternary operators.

Comment: Ok I thought so. thank you. I have one more related question. If you use a ternary operator like `user ? true : false` would that also achieve the same result as `!!user`. I guess my question is does the ternary `?` operator also ensure a Boolean type?

Comment: @privacyisimportant Yes, it does.